# THREE.JS MTLLoader path is not correct

Tags: three.js

MTL Loader is trying to load textures form wrong path.
Here is the error:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/untitled2/Users/yuqingyang/Downloads/imac%20(1)/mac_keyb.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

And it should be:

```
http://localhost:63342/untitled2/mac_keyb.jpg
```

Here is my code:

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtlLoader.setTexturePath(".");

mtlLoader.load("istuff.mtl",function (materials) {
        materials.preload();
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.load("istuff.obj", function ( object ) {
        scene.add(object);
    })
```

I used Blender to export the files, and I create the original blender file on my desktop and those texture images were under `/Users/yuqingyang/Downloads/` this path.

Then I copied blender file all images into new path which is `~/PhpProjects/untitle2`

Update:
I think I found the problem, the mtl file doesn't export right somehow:

```
newmtl clear_glass
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl keyboard_layout
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.398431 0.398431 0.398431
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd /Users/yuqingyang/Downloads/imac (1)/mac_keyb.jpg

newmtl light
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.724706 0.724706 0.724706
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Only keybord has mad_Kd attribute with a wrong path.

Comment: In what directory is your `MTL` file?

Comment: @Mugen87 It's in untitled2 directory. So i basically put all files and texture images in untitled2 directory.

Comment: What happens if you just remove `mtlLoader.setTexturePath(".");`? I guess the internal texture loader will then load the files from the same directory.

Comment: @Mugen87 If I remove `mtlLoader.setTexturePath(".");` I got `GET http://localhost:63342/Users/yuqingyang/Downloads/imac%20(1)/mac_keyb.jpg 404 (Not Found)` which doesn't make sense anyway, because I don't wanna load that texture at all, instead, there should be more another texture be loaded (It could be another issue thought).